# WINWORD.EXE remains running when filling word template

Tags: c#, ms-word

I created microsoft word template and I need  to pass data to word template.

I used following code, but after this code, word application task is not deleted from task manager, how to solve this?

WINWORD.EXE remains running when Word is closed

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oTemplatePath = "D:\\template.dotx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document wordDoc = new Document();
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        foreach (Field myMergeField in wordDoc.Fields)
        {
            Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {
                Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                if (fieldName == "lbl_name")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText("my data");
                }
            }
        }
        wordDoc.SaveAs("D:\\myfile.doc");
        wordDoc.SaveAs2("D:\\myfile.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
        wordDoc.Close();
        wordApp.Application.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Now you have completely appropriated Kamil's answer into your question, you should probably award him the answer and then post this as a new question, as it's now a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add reference to Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.
2. Create a Word Template.
3. Select insert tab in word.
4. Select Quick Parts. Then Field.
5. Select field category as MergeField. Give the MergeField name as ‘lbl_name’.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And use following code for example :

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oTemplatePath = "D:\\template.dotx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document wordDoc = new Document();
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        foreach (Field myMergeField in wordDoc.Fields)
        {
            Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {
                Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                if (fieldName == "lbl_name")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText("my data");
                }
            }
        }
        wordDoc.SaveAs("D:\\myfile.doc");
        wordDoc.SaveAs2("D:\\myfile.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
        wordDoc.Close();
        wordApp.Application.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Your efforts are appreciated, but please don't answer questions which are off-topic.